# DI ninject working for controllers but not view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

Hi I'm using ninject with an MVC app.

I'm sure I have it setup correctly as I'm able to get it working for my controllers. Here is an example for a controller and it is working correctly:

```
public class GstRateController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public GstRateController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
...
```

Then I thought it would also be good on a viewModel so I tried that with:

```
public class SettingController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public SettingController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
```

So then I instantiated the view model in a controller by:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index", Activator.CreateInstance<SettingViewModel>());
        }
```

But this is giving me the error:

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

I'm new to DI. Could someone please tell me how to achieve this for viewmodels?

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance<SettingViewModel>()` is reflections, not Ninject.  Ninject uses `kernel.Get<T>()` to explicitly resolve components.  But you shouldn't generally use the kernel at all in the middle of your app.  See Darin's answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it works for controllers and not view models is because when you install the NInject NuGet it registers a custom dependency resolver and the ASP.NET MVC framework uses either the controller factory or the dependency resolver to instantiate controllers. You can read more about dependency resolvers in [this article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html).

View models on the other hand are classes that you have specifically designed to meet the requirements of a given view. Since you are manually instantiating them a DI framework can never intercept and inject any dependencies into them. They should not have dependencies. They should be simple POCO objects that are mapped from domain models. They represent a project of on or more domain models.

Comment: So how to achieve "thick modals, thin controllers"? As far as I know anything that deals with data or data manipulation should be in a model. How should we pass data manipulator object and/or Context (i.e. entity context) objects?